# No indent in the first paragraph in amsart?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, amsart

I would like to remove all the first indentations in amsart, so I am seeking for an "indentfirst=false" command. Note that amsart do indents the first paragraphs by default (so the suggested solutions of 'No indent in the first paragraph in a section?', i.e. 'do nothing' are not relevant here).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Using an indent after section titles is a precise choice made by the editorial staff at AMS, or so it appears when reading the implementation of `amsart`.

Comment: As @egreg mentions `amsart` is for AMS publications and is not meant to be changed by users.

Comment: So changing the layout would bring up some copyright issues?

Comment: I'm waiting for a comment by @barbarabeeton about this; she will surely shed light about the matter.

Comment: @Matsmath, no not at all, just that since it build for AMS' own journals and to their in house style, there is no reason for them to make it adjustable for other uses than AMS' own.

Comment: the ams document classes, `amsart` included, are designed to meet the specs defined for ams publications.  however, there is no problem if a user wishes to make adjustments, as long as the changed file also has its name changed and a comment added to the file removing the ams from further responsibility for the file.  (my own preference is for initial paragraphs of chapters and sections to *not* be indented.  but i'm not in control of those decisions.)

Comment: Worth noting that `amsart` is not only used for AMS submissions — many people use it as their default class for preprints, personal notes, etc.  So in that setting it’s very natural to tweak it according to personal preferences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to agree with Tschichold about indentation.

Tschichold's opinion is that the *only* case where a new paragraph should not have an indentation is when it follows a centered title. The AMS thinks differently and decided for no indentation only in titles set flush left and run in (all the levels under `\section`).

If your paper in intended for submission to the AMS, don't change the setup; the editorial staff will add whatever they need (a new class, probably) and typeset the paper according to their wishes.

You're free to use `amsart` for your own writings and there's no copyright issue if you modify the appearance: there is nothing in the licensing information that prohibits using the class; the only requirement is that one can't modify the *class* file and redistribute the changed version with the same name.

How can you do? Just patch the relevant command.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@startsection}
  {\@afterindenttrue}
  {\@afterindentfalse}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
Some text to show if there is an indentation
and other text follows and other text follows
and other text follows and other text follows
and other text follows and other text follows.

\subsection{B}

Some text to show if there is an indentation
and other text follows and other text follows
and other text follows and other text follows
and other text follows and other text follows.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this interpretation is accurate in all respects except for the suggestion that ams will probably use a new class.  although there is a "designated" class for every ams journal, this journal-specific`.cls` file loads `amsart.cls` and makes only minor modifications to provide special features idiosyncratic to the particular journal.  unless one of these "non-global" features is used, `amsart` and all the ams journal-specific class files should be interchangeable.  (there are a few co-published journals that are not totally identical.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your comment; with a "new class" I meant a "different" one. How the AMS staff implements these classes shouldn't be the submitters' concern: they just have to comply with the guidelines and *not* try changing the formatting to suit their own taste.